# Difficulty Assigning Coordinates in 2-Body Problems

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

I am a little confused about assigning coordinates to 2-body problems and want to ensure my thinking is correct.

As I understand it, when working through 2-body problems I can arbitrarily assign coordinates to each object in the system. The important thing, however, is ensuring that I consistently follow those coordinate systems as I work through the problem.

In this example, (frictionless surface, massless and unstretchable rope) I have assigned coordinates so that the direction of motion is positive for both boxes. Therefore, my two equations should be

10Kg Mass: $m1a = m1g - T;$

5kg Mass : $m2a = T - m2gsinΘ$

[image]

However, because I can arbitrarily assign coordinates I can also do this

[image]

And my equations become

10 kg Mass: $-m1a = T- m1g;$

5 Kg Mass: $m2a = T - m2gsinΘ$

The only difference is that for the 10Kg mass I made m1a negative as the net force is directed opposite to the positive direction of my axis. Also, I subtracted m1g from tension as tension is in the positive direction and m2g is in the negative direction.
And by doing a little algebra, I can see that in both circumstances, both of my equations are the same.

Overall, are there any circumstances when working with two body problems that I can not simply assign coordinates independently to each object? Is the most straightforward way of solving these problems to simply assign coordinates to each object so that the acceleration is in the positive direction of the coordinate system (as I did in the 1st example), and then solve the system of equations I created?

Finally, when creating my equations do I always just subtract the force in the negative direction of the axis from the force in the positive direction of the axis, and make my net force $ma$ positive or negative depending on which direction along the axis it will be directed?